# Generic memoize function throws ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: java, memoization

I defined a generic memoize function like this.

```
public static <T, U> Function<T, U> memoize(Function<Function<T, U>, Function<T, U>> f) {
    return new Function<T, U>() {

        final Map<T, U> cache = new HashMap<>();
        final Function<T, U> body = f.apply(this);

        @Override
        public U apply(T t) {
            return cache.computeIfAbsent(t, body);
        }
    };
}
```

It works fine for single argument function.

```
Function<BigInteger, BigInteger> fibonacci =
    memoize(self -> n -> n.equals(ZERO) ? ZERO
        : n.equals(ONE) ? ONE
        : self.apply(n.subtract(ONE)).add(self.apply(n.subtract(TWO))));

for (long i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
    System.out.println(fibonacci.apply(BigInteger.valueOf(i)));
```

But when I try to apply this to a curried multi-argument function (eg tarai in  [Tak (function)-Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tak_(function))).

```
Function<Integer, Function<Integer, Function<Integer, Integer>>> tarai =
    memoize(fx -> x ->
        memoize(fy -> y ->
            memoize(fz -> z -> x <= y ? y
                : fx.apply(fx.apply(x - 1).apply(y).apply(z))
                    .apply(fx.apply(y - 1).apply(z).apply(x))
                    .apply(fx.apply(z - 1).apply(x).apply(y)))));

System.out.println(tarai.apply(12).apply(6).apply(0));
```

it throws `ConcurrentModificaionException`.
Why is this happening? What should i do?

I'm using Java 14, but I remember it worked in past versions.

Comment: Adding stack trace may help to answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

The Javadoc of [`computeIfAbsent`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/HashMap.html) says:

> This method will, on a best-effort basis, throw a ConcurrentModificationException if it is detected that the mapping function modifies this map during computation

presumably because it is internally iterating the map.

Given that, an alternative would be to do the "compute if absent" by hand:

```
if (map.containsKey(t)) {
  return map.get(t);
}
U value = body.apply(t);
map.put(t, value);
return value;
```

Comment: Why does it only occur when nested?

Comment: @saka1029 because that's the situation in which the best-effort detection of modification detects modification. Whether that's because there isn't comodification in the simple case, or it just isn't detected, I don't know, you'd need to debug it.

Answer (score 1):

`computeIfAbsent` doesn't allow recursive calls.

You pass function as second argument. That function calls `computeIfAbsent` on same object.

Implementation clearly forbid that:

```
        int mc = this.modCount;
        v = mappingFunction.apply(key);
        if (mc != this.modCount) {
            throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
        }
```

It seems like this check was introduced after `Java 1.8`.

Comment: Is it also called recursively for `fibonacci`?

Comment: I'm getting same exception for fibonacci. I'm using `java 11` though.

Comment: You don't get exception with fib, because you have it in loop. It fills map, allowing to next execution to use result of previous. If you just call `System.out.println(fibonacci.apply(BigInteger.valueOf(5)));` you will have exception.